# API for H1B Records

Tags: labor

Is an API available for downloading DOL H1B application records?

If yes, would you please direct me to where I can find this API?

Comment: Is there any plans to provide API access for H1B LCA Data?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but we do not provide that data through our API.